# creating QApplication in a different thread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qapplication

I'm trying to create QApplication in a different thread, but found 2 main problems:
1- I can't interact with GUI
2- some warnings:
`WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread. 
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread  //happens when resizing widget
QObject::killTimer: timers cannot be stopped from another thread`

here is the full code: (it may has some memory leaks but for testing purposes it fails)

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "cthread.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CThread *MyThread = new CThread;
    MyThread->start();

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

//CThread.h

```
#ifndef CTHREAD_H
#define CTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include "theqtworld.h"

class CThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CThread();
    void run( void );

private:
    TheQtWorld *mWorld;
};

#endif // CTHREAD_H
```

//CThread.cpp

```
#include "cthread.h"
#include <iostream>

CThread::CThread():mWorld(NULL)
{
}


void CThread::run()
{
    std::cout << "thread started" << std::endl;
    if(!mWorld)
        mWorld = new TheQtWorld();

    mWorld->OpenWorld();//now it will init all Qt Stuff inside

//    if(mWorld) delete mWorld;
//    emit this->exit();
}
```

//theqtworld.h

```
#ifndef THEQTWORLD_H
#define THEQTWORLD_H

#include <QObject>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

class TheQtWorld : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TheQtWorld(QObject *parent = 0);
    int OpenWorld(void);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // THEQTWORLD_H
```

//theqtworld.cpp

```
#include "theqtworld.h"

TheQtWorld::TheQtWorld(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

int TheQtWorld::OpenWorld()
{
    static int arg = 0;
    static char *b[2];
    b[0] = "a";

    QApplication *a = new QApplication(arg, b);
    a->setParent(this);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a->exec();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to create the application in another thread? I don't see any reason for doing this and I'm pretty sure its not supported by Qt.

Comment: the whole workflow will be a plugin for another non-Qt application which got its own event system, so I can't put a blocking call in the main thread

Comment: There are workarounds for this problem. Calling `QApplication::processEvents()` periodically instead of calling `QApplication::exec` may help. Google "qt integrate in another event loop". See also [this](http://jefftrull.livejournal.com/4361.html).

Comment: @PavelStrakhov this is exactly what I wanted :) , I thought the main solution is to put each event loop in a separate thread so they don't collide, but this solution of dispatching events by a non-blocking function call is much better

Comment: @MohamedSakrAboYoucuf, You can simply use a QThread! Each QThread has different event loop. You don't need a new Q*Application instance (not supported by Qt) to have anew eventLopp

Comment: @MassimoCosta It's not a "new" `QApplication`, it's the _only_ `QApplication`.

Comment: I has a QCoreApplication in the main() function. Only 1 instance of QCoreApplication or its derived (I used Q*Application notation) it.s allowed. @MohamedSakrAboYoucuf read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-qobject.html) to understand how to use different eventLoop using QThread

Comment: @MassimoCosta *QApplication is just a member which is initialized once, and I have noticed the problems in this approach "I need only 1 base instance of the QApplication family, and I MUST use main thread for GUI "and so the QApplication"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would answer my own question after understanding how to overcome this problem

first the problem was to integrate Qt GUI as a plugin into another Application, so the main issue was the Event loop collision between Qt Events and any other Application Events

my first thoughts was to separate both, so QApplication will stay at a different thread, but this was a totally wrong approach and here is what I have noticed:

1- Qt GUI Must stay in the main() thread `so there is no other place for QApplication`
2- to avoid the blocking `QApplication::exec()` , embed `QApplication::processEvents()` into the other Application Event loop

here is a working code:

```
//main.cpp

#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication mApp(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    //just for testing and holding the program so it doesn't end
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        mApp.processEvents();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

edit:thanks to pavel-strakhov for his great suggestion.

Comment: won't this consume 100% cpu?

Comment: for this test "this large for loop, and no intervals between `processEvents()`" yes it will keep the CPU busy, but once you put intervals and beautify the code you can do other stuff in the for loop "for example you can do other calculations, this for loop is just a representation of the event loop of the other application"

Comment: Do you have any advice if main thread is not available? I am trying to embed some GUI debugging window to non-qt application. The part of application that I'm trying to debug does not run in main thread.

Comment: @TomášZato it doesn't matter, you will need to call your Qt Application from your running thread, and control from there using mApp.processEvents(); as in the example above